# Find a pivot point to which minimize the "overlap" of two python lists

Tags: python, math

I have two Python lists of float numbers and I want to find a pivot point which minimizes the "overlap" of these two lists.

The problem is illustrated in the figure below, where I would like to get the cross point of the two curves (each curve can be imagined as the histogram plot of a list), and the "overlap" is defined as the green area.

For example, I have two lists [2.1, 3.5, 3.8, 3.8, 3.8, 4.2] and [3.7, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 5.0]. A good pivot point could be 4.0 (or any number between 3.8 and 4.1), where the "overlap" corresponds to only one number (4.2) from the 1st list and one number (3.7) from the 2nd list.

Apparently the set() & set() method doesn't apply here as the numbers wouldn't be the same in both lists. The only method I came up is a brute force search, starting from 4.2 and ending at 3.7, which is not ideal.

By the comments, I need to separate it into two questions:
1) What's the Python solution to find such a pivot point of the two lists? 
2) Much better, maybe too much to ask it here, but how to get a statistically rigor solution to minimize the separation of the two set of values? I am not sure if I can assume a Gaussian distribution of the values, but let's assume we can if that helps to formulate a solution.

[image]

Comment: Are the lists always sorted (or if not is it okay to sort them)?  If so it seems like you only have two possibilities to consider (the last element of the first list and the first element of the last list).

Comment: Please define "pivot point". The overlap between those two intervals seems to be independent of any extraneous point, but you seem to be treating this overlap as a function of some extraneous point, a function to be minimized.

Comment: @Samwise I'm not sure that's true. I think any value between min(max(list1),max(list2)) and max(min(list1),min(list2)) would be a possible solution.

Comment: @JohnColeman John, the "pivot point" would be the cross point of the two curves I gave in the picture. Is there a better name for it? Note here what I have are the discrete values, not the distribution curve of them.

Comment: How do you get a curve for the list? The picture is nice but doesn't seem to be related to the lists.

Comment: @Samwise The example I gave may not be a good one. The problem should be better understood if looking at the distribution curves of the numbers as in the picture posted. The overlap should in theory be uniquely defined as the cross point of their distribution curves.

Comment: @JohnColeman Imagine each lists have 1 million values. The curves would be the histogram plot of the values, where the height is how many of them falls in a bin of x+delta.

Comment: You could do something like get kernel density estimates for the density curves and then use numerical methods to find an intersection point -- which might fail to be unique if the distributions are not unimodal. There must be some tools in the numpy/scipy/pandas universe for doing such things.

Comment: Are these ideas of distributions and curves actually fundamental to your problem or are they just the way you are imagining it? I was assuming that what you needed was to identify a value X such that the statement "all values less than X are from list 1 and all values more than X are from list 2" misclassified the smallest number of items possible. By talking about curves you seem to be suggesting that the lists are just samples from a larger population and you want to infer a population classifier, which is a harder problem.

Comment: To add to my previous comments, if you have strong enough assumptions the problem might be almost trivial. For example -- if each of the lists are samples from a Gaussian population.

Comment: @JohnColeman John, what happens if I assume a Gaussian population for both lists. I still need to calculate the cross point, and see how big the intersections could be.

Comment: What's the actual meaning of values in these lists? What's the real purpose of the expected point? What's the actual problem we are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have two lists **a** and **b**. We are looking for such a value **x** for which the cumulative probability of higher values in **a** is equal to cumulative probability of lower values in **b**.

Formally:

```
1 − CDF(a, x) == CDF(b, x)
```

Alternatively:

```
1 − CDF(a, x) − CDF(b, x) == 0
```

Let's implement it in Python.

```py
import itertools
import random

def boundary(a, b):
    """Return interval of boundary values."""
    # Calculate probability density function for both list
    # Merge lists and sort them by their values
    cc = sorted(itertools.chain(
        ((x, 1/len(a)) for i, x in enumerate(a)),
        ((x, 1/len(b)) for i, x in enumerate(b))))
    # Mark all values with 1 − CDF(a, x) − CDF(b, x)
    pp = [(x[0], 1-sum(z[1] for z in cc[:i+1])) for i, x in enumerate(cc)]
    # Find index of a value closest to zero
    m = min(enumerate(pp), key=lambda x: abs(x[1][1]))
    # Return range of values
    index = m[0]
    return pp[index][0], pp[index+1][0]
```

Test simple cases:

```py
print(boundary([1, 2], [3, 4]))      # -> (2, 3)
print(boundary([1], [3]))            # -> (1, 3)
print(boundary([1, 3], [2, 4]))      # -> (2, 3)
```

And test a more complicated case:

```py
a = sorted(random.gauss(0, 1) for _ in range(300))
b = sorted(random.gauss(1, 1) for _ in range(200))
print(boundary(a, b))                # -> approx (0.5, 0.5 + Δ)
```

Please note that the algorithm correctly processes lists of different lengths.
And with slight performance optimizations it can successfully handle lists with millions of items.

Comment: Thanks, but seems there are some assumptions that I am not aware. For lists a = [1.0]*99 + [3.5, 3.8, 4.2], b = [3.7, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 5.0], it returns a boundary of (3.5, 3.7). I wish it to be (3.8, 4.1), which minimizes the overlap. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you consider only numbers in the list you can expect different result. As soon as you consider probability density the situation becomes different. The probability values are very low on the right tail of the first list but are very high near the centre of the second list. For this reason the calculated interval really leads to the smallest area as you expected. I consider the calculated results correct.

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to use a decision classifier to determine the best separation point.

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier # Import Decision Tree Classifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split # Import train_test_split function
from sklearn import metrics #Import scikit-learn metrics module for accuracy calculation

# Setup Data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Feature': [1.0, 2.1, 3.5, 4.2,3.7, 4.1, 5.0],'Label':[0,0,0,0,1,1,1]})

feature_cols = ['Feature']
X = df[feature_cols] # Features
y = df.Label # Target variable

# Create Decision Tree classifer object (use max_depth of 1 to have one boundary)
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth = 1)

# Train Decision Tree Classifer
clf = clf.fit(X, y)

# Found decision boundary by creating test data in 0.1 steps from min to max
# (i.e. 1 to 5)
arr = np.arange(1, 5.1, 0.1)
test_set = pd.DataFrame({'Feature': arr})

# Create predictor so we can see where boundary is created
y_pred = clf.predict(test_set)

indexes = np.where(y_pred > 0)   # all points with label 1
pivot_index = indexes[0][0]      # first point with label 1
pivot_value = arr[pivot_index]   # value is pivot value
print(f'Pivot value: {pivot_value}')
```

**Output**

```
Pivot value: 3.7000000000000024
```

Comment: Thanks Darry. This is definitely a nice answer to my problem. I chose the answer with CDF because that one returns a more deterministic result, while decision tree has some "randomness" in it.

Comment: @Luke--no worries, the CDF solution looks very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly the values you are looking for do not necessarily belong to the lists. 
If that is the case you can "artificially" resample your lists with decimal spacing between min and max of the original lists, transform them to "sets" and compute the intersection between them.